# Pairwise dissimilarities nesting a time-series loop inside a site loop - multiple times

Tags: r, loops, time-series, nested-loops, pairwise

I have a data frame where rows are years (~30 years) and sites (~300 sites) and columns are species abundances (~200 spp).

The data looks like:

| Site | Year | Specie 1 | Specie 2 | Species n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Site 1 | Year 1 | 0.4 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| Site 1 | Year 2 | 0.8 | 0.5 | 1.0 |
| Site 1 | Year 3 | 0.0 | 0.7 | 1.3 |
| Site 1 | Year 4 | 0.0 | 0.4 | 1.6 |
| Site 2 | Year 1 | 1.2 | 0.1 | 0.4 |
| Site 2 | Year 2 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.5 |
| Site 2 | Year 3 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.4 |
| Site 3 | Year 1 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Site 3 | Year 2 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.8 |
| Site 3 | Year 3 | 0.5 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Site 3 | Year 4 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.3 |

*Note the dataset has inconsistent year surveys.

What I need is to build a nested loop of time series (years) inside a site loop. Then, run temporal pairwise comparisons (e.g., using betapart or vegan packages in R) by two different scenarios: 1) anchoring the first year (year 1) of each site and comparing the subsequent years (i.e., yr1 vs yr2; yr1 vs yr3; yr1 vs yr4...), and 2) comparing dissimilarities between successive years (i.e., yr1 vs yr2; yr2 vs yr3; yr3 vs yr4...).

I do not have any final code but think I need to run something like this (I am sure is very much more complex than this):

```
# prior need to define empty matrix to beta outputs
beta.matrix <- data.frame(curp = df$Site, Year = df$Year, beta.bray.bal=NA, beta.bray.gra=NA, beta.bray=NA)

# nested loop pairwise dissimilarities
for(i in 1:unique(df$Site)){ # outer loop are sites
  
  for(j in 1:(nrow(df$Year))){ # the inner loop are years and will run one time for each iteration of the outer loop.
    
   beta.x <- beta.pair.abund(x, index.family="bray") # this is the pairwise function in betapart package in R
    
    #the function *beta.pair.abund* returns three outputs that I expect to store in the empty matrix I defined previusly: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betapart/betapart.pdf

    beta.matrix$beta.bray.bal[i]<-as.matrix(beta.x[[1]])[unique(df$Site)+i, i] 
    beta.matrix$beta.bray.gra[i]<-as.matrix(beta.x[[2]])[unique(df$Site)+i, i]
    beta.matrix$beta.bray[i]<-as.matrix(beta.x[[3]])[unique(df$Site)+i, i]
    
  }

 }
```

Any thoughts on how to do it will be very well appreciated.

Comment: 1) Your first `for()` syntax is incorrect. It should be either `for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Site)))` if you want a vector of integers, or `for(i in c(unique(df$Site)))` if you want the site values. 2) In your question it's not clear whether you want to compare only within sites, or across/between sites. I believe it's the former, but either way run this to see what your loop is doing `for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Site))){for(j in 1:nrow(df)){print(paste("Site ==", i, "and Year ==", df[j,2]))}}`.

Comment: Hi @Leroy, thanks! I want to compare within the same time series (i.e., unique sites), i.e., how site 1 change over time, then the same process with site 2, etc.  I ran the code you said and this is printing a list of each site and year combination in my data frame. My question is how to use this to run a specific function (pairwise comparations within the same time series of each site), e.g: `x <- beta.pair.abund(rbind(site1_yr1, site1_yr2), index.family="bray")` i.e., what is the dissimilarity between the second and first year of site 1, and then do this for all the time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on the sample data you provided. Some modifications to the code will be required for it to work on your full dataset:

```
library(betapart)

df <- data.frame(Site = paste(rep("Site", 11), c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)),
                 Year = paste(rep("Year", 11), c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4)),
                 `Specie 1` = c(0.4, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0),
                 `Specie 2` = c(0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 `Specie 3` = c(0.0, 1.0, 1.3, 1.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.3),
                 check.names=FALSE)

# Define empty matrix for beta outputs (note this differs from 
# your example as it has three added columns to accommodate
# both "subsequent" and "successive" outputs)
beta.matrix <- data.frame(curp = df$Site, 
                          Year = df$Year, 
                          subs.beta.bray.bal=NA, 
                          subs.beta.bray.gra=NA, 
                          subs.beta.bray=NA,
                          succ.beta.bray.bal=NA, 
                          succ.beta.bray.gra=NA, 
                          succ.beta.bray=NA)

# Create loop vector for every Site
for(i in unique(df$Site)) {
  
  # Get row index for first value of each group e.g. "Year 1"
  x <- min(which(df$Site == i)) 
  # Counter, only needed for calculating "successive years"
  y <- 0
  
  # Create loop vector one less than site observations 
  # e.g. exclude "Year 1"
  for(j in 1:(length(which(df$Site == i))-1)) {
    
    # Calculate beta.pair.abund for x and x+j (subsequent years)
    # ATTENTION: edit column index "3:5" to match your actual data
    # e.g. df[c(x,x+j),3:200]
    beta.subs <- beta.pair.abund(df[c(x,x+j),3:5], index.family="bray")
    # Add result to beta.matrix (leave the column index as is)
    beta.matrix[x+j,3:5] <- do.call(cbind, beta.subs)
    
    # Calculate beta.pair.abund for x+y and x+j (successive years)
    # ATTENTION: edit column index "3:5" to match your actual data
    # e.g. df[c(x+y, x+j),3:200]
    beta.succ <- beta.pair.abund(df[c(x+y, x+j),3:5], index.family="bray")
    # Add result to beta.matrix
    beta.matrix[x+j,6:8] <- do.call(cbind, beta.succ)
    # Increase "counter" by 1 for each inner loop iteration
    y <- y + 1

  }
  
}

beta.matrix
#      curp   Year subs.beta.bray.bal subs.beta.bray.gra subs.beta.bray   succ.beta.bray.bal succ.beta.bray.gra succ.beta.bray
# 1  Site 1 Year 1                 NA                 NA             NA                   NA                 NA             NA
# 2  Site 1 Year 2         0.00000000         0.70370370     0.70370370           0.00000000         0.70370370     0.70370370
# 3  Site 1 Year 3         1.00000000         0.00000000     1.00000000           0.25000000         0.05232558     0.30232558
# 4  Site 1 Year 4         1.00000000         0.00000000     1.00000000           0.15000000         0.00000000     0.15000000
# 5  Site 2 Year 1                 NA                 NA             NA                   NA                 NA             NA
# 6  Site 2 Year 2         0.06666667         0.05833333     0.12500000           0.06666667         0.05833333     0.12500000
# 7  Site 2 Year 3         0.00000000         0.09677419     0.09677419           0.00000000         0.03448276     0.03448276
# 8  Site 3 Year 1                 NA                 NA             NA                   NA                 NA             NA
# 9  Site 3 Year 2         0.00000000         0.25000000     0.25000000           0.00000000         0.25000000     0.25000000
# 10 Site 3 Year 3         0.00000000         0.33333333     0.33333333           0.13333333         0.07878788     0.21212121
# 11 Site 3 Year 4         0.00000000         0.81818182     0.81818182           0.00000000         0.66666667     0.66666667
```

Note that this will return NAs for "Year 1" for each group. This is expected behaviour.

One further point, there are better approaches than loops in R. Although your data has only ~9,000 rows and this loop should take less than one minute, R handles vectorised methods much better. Check out the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) for faster, non-loop alternatives using packages such as `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

**UPDATE:**

In response to comments below, here is a loop to compare across sites by year using the same sample df as before. It involves a slightly different "beta.matrix1" df to hold the results. It also cycles through only those sites that have a corresponding "Year" e.g. in the example data, as "Site 2" has no record for "Year 4", "Site 1" only matches "Year 4" with "Site 3" etc. This solves the issue of sites with differing observation counts. This is achieved via using `which()`to create the "y" vector in the following loop:

```
# Create empty df with 0 rows to hold results
beta.matrix1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 6))
# Rename columns. "Site" and "SiteN" are the pairs being matched
colnames(beta.matrix1) <- c("Site", "SiteN", "Year",
                            "year.beta.bray.bal",
                            "year.beta.bray.gra",
                            "year.beta.bray")

# Loop through vector of every unique site
for(i in unique(df$Site)) {

  # Loop through vector of row indices for i e.g. every year
  for(j in which(df$Site == i)) {
    
    # Create vector of row indices from every other "Site" for the current
    # "Year" being processed in i e.g. If "Site 1 Year 1" is the current
    # value, then get every "Site n Year 1" EXCLUDING "Site 1 Year 1"
    y <- which(df$Year == df$Year[j] & df$Site != i)
    
    # Loop through every Site that has matching Year
    for(k in y) {
      
      # If a pair has already been processed...
      if(paste(df$Site[k], i) %in% paste(beta.matrix1$Site, beta.matrix1$SiteN)) {
        
        # skip to the next iteration
        next
        
      } else {
      
      # Calculate beta.pair.abund for j and k (Site comparison).
      # ATTENTION: edit column index "3:5" to match your actual data
      # Note this took two steps in previous loop
      beta.year <- do.call(cbind, beta.pair.abund(df[c(j,k),3:5],
                                                  index.family="bray"))
      # Create list with current Sites, Year, and beta.pair.abund result
      z <- c(i, df$Site[k], df$Year[j], beta.year)
      # Add result to beta.matrix1
      beta.matrix1[nrow(beta.matrix1)+1,] <- z
      
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}


# Convert beta.year results back to numeric
beta.matrix1[,4:6] <- as.numeric(unlist(beta.matrix1[,4:6]))

beta.matrix1
#      Site  SiteN   Year year.beta.bray.bal year.beta.bray.gra year.beta.bray
# 1  Site 1 Site 2 Year 1         0.00000000         0.61904762     0.61904762
# 2  Site 1 Site 3 Year 1         0.00000000         0.76470588     0.76470588
# 3  Site 1 Site 2 Year 2         0.13333333         0.18245614     0.31578947
# 4  Site 1 Site 3 Year 2         0.11111111         0.10840108     0.21951220
# 5  Site 1 Site 2 Year 3         0.71428571         0.05042017     0.76470588
# 6  Site 1 Site 3 Year 3         0.33333333         0.09523810     0.42857143
# 7  Site 1 Site 3 Year 4         0.00000000         0.73913043     0.73913043
# 8  Site 2 Site 3 Year 1         0.05882353         0.26032541     0.31914894
# 9  Site 2 Site 3 Year 2         0.00000000         0.09090909     0.09090909
# 10 Site 2 Site 3 Year 3         0.35714286         0.02216749     0.37931034
```

Note that this will ignore pairs that have already been processed e.g. if "Site 1 Year 1 / Site 2 Year 1" exists, then "Site 2 Year 1 / Site 1 Year 1" will not be added. This ensures only unique pairs are recorded. Further, it's not ideal that the `beta.pair.abund()` results have to be coerced back to numeric and other approaches would avoid this. However, as it stands, the results seem robust.

Comment: Hi Leroy, this is great, thanks for doing it very clearly! It worked when I edit the column index to match my own data. Just wondering if I want to do the same process but now across/between sites (i.e., site1 vs site2, site2 vs site3, site1 vs site3), also considering the two logical processes through time. I  tried specifying another inner loop `for (k in 1: (length(df$site == i)))` and then replacing the x for a k in the beta.pair.abun functions, but it didn't work. I think I need to do a separate code, an empty matrix and a completely different loop code. Any thoughts will be great!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Do you mean "Site 1 Year 1" vs "Site 2 Year 2",  "Site 1 Year 1"  vs "Site 2 Year 3",  "Site 1 Year 1"  vs "Site 2 Year 4" etc.?  Or is there a function in `betapart` that compares an aggregates of all observations in "Site 1" vs "Site 2"? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't make it very explicit. Basically, comparing by sites in the same year; for example, comparing among sites in the year 1: "Site 1_year 1" vs "Site 2_year 1"; Site 2_year 1" vs "Site 3_year 1"; "Site 1_year 1 vs Site 3_year 1". Then, the same process with year 2 among all sites, then year 3, etc. I know there are not the same length of years for each site in the former dataframe, but let's suppose there are 3 sites * 4 years each. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @L Tyrone. Just reaching an old post to ask a specific issue. According to the loop to calculate the successive pairwise comparison (year-to-year), I'd like to know whether there is a way to change the loop biannually instead of annually; i.e., pairwise comparison in this way: ("yr 1" vs "yr 3); ("yr 3" vs "yr 5"); ("yr 5" vs "yr 7") and so on.

Comment: @JaGo - sure. Does that also include "yr 2 vs yr 4" etc.?

Comment: @L Tyrone No, just every two years. Basically what I want is to compare the FIRST YEAR AVAILABLE and then biannually after that. The problem is that my database is unbalanced and year 1 is not the same for everyone. For example, site1 starts in 2005, and site2 in 2006. So, using this example, for site1 I'd like to compare 2005-2007-2009; for site2 2006-2008-2010, etc.

Comment: @JaGo - this is getting beyond the scope of the comments section :) It will be better to post this as a separate question. In your new question, 1) using `dput()`, include a small sample dataset with enough rows to reproduce all the scenarios you describe, 2) an example of your desired output, 3) a description of how you want to handle the unbalanced year 1 issue and if necessary, an extra column with the actual year e.g. 2005. Tag me in your new question and I'll have a look at it. Thanks